# How to resolve java.lang.outofmemoryerror permgen space error in GGTS

Tags: java, grails, grails-2.0

I am using [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite](http://grails.org/products/ggts) to work on my Grails project. Most of the time I am getting weird **permgen space** error while running my application on debug mode. I am trying to increase my permanent generation space to -XX:MaxPermSize=256m but nothing working for me.

here is my GGTS.ini file ...

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.springsource.ggts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I am still getting same permgen space error most of the time. Please give me some pointers how to overcome this issue.

**UPDATE**

I changed my MaxPermSize to 512m but no luck. Still I am getting Permgen space error.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be modifying the GGTS.ini that will just effect the UI environment. You should be adding these parameters at the following location. Window->Preferences (Search for grails in preferences) Select Grails Launch and update the Default JVM Args. These arguments would be passed to your grails process and will solve the issue.